# Div with scrollbar inside div with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, css

So basically I have this div with `height:400px` and inside of it I have a div with dynamic height, what I want to do is if the div inside the main div exceeds `400px` in height then it should have a scrollbar so I can scroll to the bottom of it. Can I do this in css or I need javascript ?

Comment: Does inside div: `height:400px;overflow:auto;` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
overflow-y:auto
```

with your parent div container.

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2Y9a/)

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only good reason to do this is if you cannot modify the div with overflow:hidden and need a background color/border that resizes with content.

HTML

```
<div class="d1">

    <div class="d2">
          <div class="d3"> D3 will resize with content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.d1{height:400px; overflow:hidden}
.d2{height:400px; overflow:auto; }
.d3{background-color:#F00;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:

```
#container
{
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.dynamic-height
{
    height: auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/NfsSv/)